# Flutter - How to access Wifi details?

Tags: flutter, wifi, ssid

I'm setting up an IoT device over Bluetooth. To do so, I need to get the Wifi details from my user. For simplicity I would like to get a list of the networks based off of connection levels.

Comment: have you looked into a package like this one: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/wifi#-example-tab-  https://github.com/once10301/wifi

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for connectivity details, then check [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/connectivity) out:

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';

var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
  // I am connected to a mobile network.
} else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
  // I am connected to a wifi network.
}
```

Here is how you find the current SSID:

```
try {
  wifiBSSID = await _connectivity.getWifiBSSID();
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  wifiBSSID = "Failed to get Wifi BSSID";
}
```

An alternative is the [FlutterWifi](https://github.com/alternadom/WiFiFlutter) library, but its features on iOS are greatly limited as of now.

Comment: This is what I eventually used for this. Grabbing the SSID is about all you can do on this Flutter at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
To use the google_mlkit_barcode_scanning plugin for scanning WiFi details, you can follow these steps:

Add the google_mlkit_barcode_scanning plugin to your pubspec.yaml file
```

dependencies:
google_mlkit_barcode_scanning: ^0.8.0

```
BarcodeScanner barcodeScanner = GoogleMlKit.vision.barcodeScanner();
List<Barcode> barcodes = await barcodeScanner.processImage(inputImage);
for (Barcode barcode in barcodes) {
if (barcode.type == BarcodeType.wifi) {
String ssid = barcode.wifi!.ssid;
String password = barcode.wifi!.password;
String encryptionType = barcode.wifi!.encryptionType;
print('SSID: $ssid');
print('Password: $pass`enter code here`word');
print('Encryption Type: $encryptionType');
}
}
```